# List files in Glacier with AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-glacier

I need to delete files stored in a Glacier Vault, but  AWS CLI needs the object id and I can't execute the correct command to obtain this id.

Anyone knows the command to see the file id with AWS CLI?

Comment: Can you tell us what code you've tried?

Comment: With shell script and this : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glacier/index.html

Comment: Can you show us the shell script?

Comment: only: aws glacier delete-archive --account-id XXXXXX --vault-name XXXX --archive-id ????  I don´t know how to obtain the "archive-id". In AWS CLI documentation, i can´t see this command to list the files in Glacier.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `aws glacier initiate-job` to obtain an inventory of an Amazon Glacier vault.

From the [Amazon Glacier documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glacier/initiate-job.html):

> The following command initiates a job to get an inventory of the vault my-vault:

```
aws glacier initiate-job --account-id - --vault-name my-vault --job-parameters '{"Type": "inventory-retrieval"}'
```

Once the job completes, you can call `aws glacier get-job-output`. The inventory will include the `archive-id` (files are called **archives** in Glacier).

Here is a sample output from the [`get-job-output` documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glacier/get-job-output.html):

```
{"VaultARN":"arn:aws:glacier:us-west-2:0123456789012:vaults/my-vault","InventoryDate":"2015-04-07T00:26:18Z","ArchiveList":[{"ArchiveId":"kKB7ymWJVpPSwhGP6ycSOAekp9ZYe_--zM_mw6k76ZFGEIWQX-ybtRDvc2VkPSDtfKmQrj0IRQLSGsNuDp-AJVlu2ccmDSyDUmZwKbwbpAdGATGDiB3hHO0bjbGehXTcApVud_wyDw","ArchiveDescription":"multipart upload test","CreationDate":"2015-04-06T22:24:34Z","Size":3145728,"SHA256TreeHash":"9628195fcdbcbbe76cdde932d4646fa7de5f219fb39823836d81f0cc0e18aa67"}]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! I try this option :D

Comment: I tried your solution but I have: `as Amazon Glacier has not yet generated an initial inventory for this vault`. Am I supposed to wait?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to wait. Could be up to 24 hours.

Comment: You need to wait up to 24 hours but only AFTER upload the first archive. It is mean that if you just create a vault and did not upload the archive you will never get "inventory-retrieval"

Comment: After initiating the job, to check its status: `aws glacier list-jobs --account-id - --vault-name my-vault`. When it completes, the syntax for the command to get its output is `aws glacier get-job-output --account-id - --vault-name my-vault --job-id id outfile`

Answer (score 4):

This's ok

```
aws glacier initiate-job --account-id - --vault-name my-vault --job-parameters "{ \"Type\": \"inventory-retrieval\" }"
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that how the strings are quoted depending on whether you are using Linux or Mac or Powershell or Windows. See [AWS doc on quoting strings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-parameters-quoting-strings.html)

For the Windows command prompt, this works:

```
aws glacier initiate-job --account-id 123456789012  --vault-name myvault --job-parameters "{\"Type\": \"inventory-retrieval\"}"
```

For PowerShell use single quotes around the JSON but still escape the double quotes.  With Linux and Mac you shouldn't need to escape the double quotes.